# How can I solve theano GPU pygpu error on Google Colab?

Tags: gpu, theano, google-colaboratory, theano-cuda

I'm using theano gpu on Google Colab and I get this error:

```
ERROR (theano.gpuarray): pygpu was configured but could not be imported or is too old (version 0.7 or higher required)
```

I've set:

```
import os
os.environ["THEANO_FLAGS"]="device=cuda, floatX=float32"
```

And changed the runtime type to hardware accelerator 'GPU'

Could you please help me solving this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you follow these [installation docs](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_ubuntu.html#with-pip) ? Otherwise provide detailled installation info

Comment: Yes, I've followed the installation docs.
I've tried both the installation via pip and conda.

With pip it gives me the error I've mentioned, while with conda it gives me this other error:
pygpu.gpuarray.GpuArrayException: b'Could not load "libnvrtc.so": libnvrtc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'